# Most Efficient Way to find the logn th Maximum in a Max Heap

Tags: data-structures, max, time-complexity, heap, max-heap

The title says it all; What is the most efficient way to find the **log n**th maximum number in a max heap with **n** elements?
**ps**: The text book I'm reading vaguely explained a solution with time complexity of `O(lognloglogn)` by using another heap that I can't understand, can we do better than that?

Comment: An obvious, and not very interesting, solution is to simply do log n extract-max operations, resulting in running time `O((log n)^2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `H` be the original max-heap. Let `H'` be another max-heap, initially empty, that operates on pairs `(index, value)` of elements from the first heap and orders the pairs based on the second component.

1. `H'.push(0, H[0])`
2. `count = ceil(log n)`
3. `while count > 0 do`

   4. `(i, v) := H'.extract-max()` // takes `O(log log n)` time
   5. `H'.push(2i+1, H[2i+1])` if `H[2i+1]` exists // `O(log log n)` time
   6. `H'.push(2i+1, H[2i+2])` if `H[2i+2]` exists // `O(log log n)` time
   7. `count := count - 1`
4. return `v`

The reason we have `O(log log n)` bounds on running times of operations of `H'` is that `H'` contains at most `log n` elements and each operation runs in time logarithmic in the number of elements of the heap, which is `O(log log n)`.

The total running time is obviously `O(log n log log n)`. I'm assuming the original max-heap `H` is represented with an array.

Comment: how do you extract the min from H in O(log logn) time? That heap contains n elements,

Comment: @Amen no need to extract min, you need to extract max. And `max` is, by the construction of the heap, at index 0 of the array representing the heap...

Comment: I'm sorry my comment was wrong, I meant to say you can't do line 4. of your code in that time complexity.

Comment: Well, I claim you can. `H'` contains _at most_ `log n` items where `n` is the number of items in `H` (note that `H` and `H'` are different max-heaps). Since `H'.extract-max()` runs in time `O(log (H'.size())` and `H'.size()=O(log n)`, we have that its running time is `O(log log n)`.

Comment: Aha, now I see it's been changed, initially you were extracting min from H. :)

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo, sorry (but the description was correct).